# is it correct to unbind and rebind a function within a click?

Tags: jquery, function, binding, click

If I have a function that does something within a click event, is it correct to unbind that function and then rebind?

Currently I have a function that popsup when click a button. It will resize and everything, but it works well within the function. My problem now is, when i .hide() this popup, this function is still active if I try to resize the browser (I did not assign this popup on browser resize). Now am I supposed to just unbind this function when I click it?

Thanks

My Code

```
function popup() {

$(window).resize(function () {  
var maskHeight = $(window).height();  
var maskWidth = $(window).width();
var dialogTop =  (maskHeight  - $('#dialog-box').height())/3;  
var dialogLeft = (maskWidth - $('#dialog-box').width())/2; 
$('#dialog-overlay').css({ height:$(document).height(), width:$(document).width() }).show();
$('#dialog-box').css({ top: dialogTop, left: dialogLeft, position:"fixed"}).show();
}).resize();

$('#dialog-message').html(message);

};

$('#register').click(function(){
popup();
$('html').unbind(popup);    
return false;
});
```

Not even sure if this is right to unbind it. But it does not seem to work when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to unbind event handlers once they are no longer needed. You may choose to not unbind them if they have no negative effects. However if you feel they slow down the script then unbinding them is a really good idea to boost performance given they aren't needed any more.

Also instead of unbinding, you may check a flag in your event handler before executing any code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.
If you're using `$.bind` then it's fairly easy to bind and unbind the event as necessary.

If you're using some form of event delegation, it's probably easier to maintain an object that contains state.

```
state = {
    my_event: false
}
```

and then inside the click event:

```
if (!state.my_event)
{
    do_something();
}
```